# How to fix the error `Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined`

Tags: javascript, html, json, reactjs, redux

update 1:

I updated the fiddle but still I am facing an error **_this.state.concat is not a function**, can you please help me  https://codesandbox.io/s/40mmrl9059

When I click the favourites icon in the card, then the card should be shown in the favourites tab which is the outer. For that I am trying to pass the value from child to the parent, so I am using setState in handleClick method.

But right now I am getting an error

> Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined

Can you tell me how to fix it?

(providing my code snippet and sandbox below.
- cards code is in actual-card.js and tab code is in tab-demo.js)

https://codesandbox.io/s/40mmrl9059

```
state = {
  value: 0,
  top: false,
  left: false,
  bottom: false,
  right: false,
  favorites: []
};

// props
handleClick(prop) {
  console.log("actualCard--->");
  //console.log("event.currentTarget--->", currentTarget.relatedTarget);
  this.setState({ favorites: this.state.concat(prop) });
}



<IconButton
  // onClick={this.handleClickOpen}
  onClick={this.handleClick}
  aria-label="Add to favorites"
>

<Tabs
  value={value}
  onChange={this.handleChange}
  scrollable
  scrollButtons="on"
  indicatorColor="primary"
  textColor="primary"
>
<Tab label="Search" icon={<PhoneIcon />} />
<Tab
  favorites={favorites}
  label="Favorites"
  icon={<FavoriteIcon />}
 />
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind `this` to your event handler

Try using an arrow function like `handleClick = (prop) => {//code}`

Comment: I updated the fiddle but still I am facing an error _this.state.concat is not a function, can you please help me  https://codesandbox.io/s/40mmrl9059

Comment: I'm a bit uncomfortable telling you how to fix all of your code because this is starting to look like a homework problem? Simply put, you're calling concat on this.state. this.state does not have a concat function because it's an object. What you're trying to do is set this.state.favorites to equal some prop you pass in, presumably this.prop.favorites. You shouldn't be concatting into this.state. I think you're not understanding some fundamental react concepts that are out of scope for this question.

Comment: Hey this is not homework problem...I went through lot of tutorials, I thought I will implement and see... so that I will get a relatime experience...not sure how to display the favourites card in the favourites tab...can you help me so that in future I can fix it myself...

Comment: It's really hard to help you when i'm not sure what your use case is. There seems to be a lot of missing logic and I can't easily fill in the gaps here. You should break the problems down into smaller bits.

Comment: hey I printed the console and saw I dont see concat, when you click  favourite icons in the cards tab it should save in the favourites tab....thats the outer tab...all the cards tab is in favourites-cards.js

Comment: printed values ---> {value: 0, top: false, left: false, bottom: false, right: false, …}
bottom
:
false
favorites
:
[]
left
:
false
right
:
false
top
:
false
value
:
0
__proto__
:
Object